# Parse Time String to DateTime format for HH:MM format of DateTimePicker - C#, WFA

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I am trying to take a time string in the format of HH:MM such as 18:30 and turning this into a DateTime string.
I have tried many different methods such as using ParseExact (as seen below), however even when using this code, it still outputs the DateTime string as both the date and the time.

```
dtpTime.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Classes.SystemClasses.Booking.getBookingTime(), "H:mm", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Which outputs:

> 20/02/2019 18:56:00

The value in `Classes.SystemClasses.Booking.getBookingTime()` is 18:56 which is the value I wish to enter into a DateTimePicker on a form in the format of HH:MM

Any help to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated and if the explanation is not clear enough, please feel free to ask myself any questions.

Thanks, Ryan.

Comment: It's hard to understand whats the issue. Can you share the expected output you need?

Comment: First, yo should use _HH:mm_ instead of _H:mm_. Than you can try `ToShortTimeString()` or `ToLongTimeString()` function

Comment: @Stormhashe The output I'm looking for is in a HH:MM format like 18:30 in DateTime so that it can be put into a DateTimePicker. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Tried using HH:mm, giving the same output as using H:mm. Also, since I need the final output to be in a format of DateTime, the ToShortTimeString() or ToShortTimeString() won't do what I need unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanS you can't put that output format in a DateTime variable. The DateTime itself has always the same pattern, and what you can do is convert it to a string with the needed output. As the name suggest, its DATETime, not Time.

Comment: @Stormhashe Ah ok. What's the best way to convert the string in that format into a date time picker? Thanks.

Comment: I'll post as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is hold a **TIME** inside a **Date**Time variable. That is not possible, as the name suggest, this type is used to hold a Date and a Time. If you need only the Time part of the date, you need to convert it to a string:

```cs
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(Classes.SystemClasses.Booking.getBookingTime(), "HH:mm", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: When doing it this way, how do I put it into the DateTimePicker afterwards? I have tried to do dtpTime.Text = time as well as dtpTime.Value = time, however the .Value method doesn't work as it can't implicitly convert 'string' to 'System.DateTime'. 
When using the .Text method the time variable doesn't go into the Date Time Picker either.
Thanks!

Comment: You can't put a TIME inside a DateTime type. Please explain the problem further, why do you need only a Time, if its a DateTime picker? Are you not using the Date part for anything at all?

Comment: I have been assigned to make a bus booking system and I am using DateTimePickers for the pickup / dropoff time. I have multiple times such as Pickup, Dropoff, Return Pickup and Return Dropoff times and only the one date. So, I need multiple DateTimePickers to pick both the single date and multiple times. I was able to put only the date into the DTP, however can't figure out how to do it with time. Thanks.

Comment: I see. I will need more information to help. Can you post your front-end code for your time picker, and share what technology you are using (angular, jquery, vue etc?)

Comment: Here's the frontend of it in a pastebin since it's too long to post here [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qUr4ciHf) and I am using C# with Visual Studio 2015.